# React-Native, Global State?

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to find a way to have a global state in React-Native. A shared state between multiple components, with auto re-rendering like a normal state. But for all the components.

I don't want to use redux.

Comment: Do you have a parent component? You could have it as a state in that component and pass it down as props to the other components.

Comment: You just defined react context

Comment: @Cristy I use ``react-native-router-flux``

Comment: @Federkun Can you share more details?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even tho i said in my question that i didn't want to use Redux, i figured it out and i found out it is pretty simple once you get the basics of it.

Comment: It is for me..?

Comment: I asked my question, didn't find an answer, found my own answer, and then accepted my own answer in which I'm telling what i did to solve my question. (:

Comment: Can you elaborate, how did you do it without redux?? @Hobey823

Comment: please tell us how you do this